# How to pass an Angular's value to a function

Tags: angularjs

I want to call a function `fadeOut()` passing to it an index number generated by ng-repeat. I tried this

```
   <img ng-src={{element.image}} class="portofolio-image" 
id="portofolio-image{{$index}}"
 ng-click="fadeOut({{$index}})">
```

but there is a parsing error, and this

```
    <img ng-src={{element.image}} class="portofolio-image"
 id="portofolio-image{{$index}}"
 ng-click="fadeOut('{{$index}}')">
```

which passes the "{{$index}}" string. Any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: `ng-click="fadeOut($index)"` without curly brackets

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use fadeOut($index) as follows:

```
    <img ng-src={{element.image}} 
     class="portofolio-image" 
     id="portofolio-image{{$index}}" 
     ng-click="fadeOut($index)">
```